# How to call an external script using cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

How would I load an external script using cypress?

in my code normally you call javascript scripts like this:

`<script src="https://myexternalscript"></script>`

But lets say I want to load a domain in cypress but then I want an extra script loaded onto the page, how could I do that?

Comment: Are you sure you use that format usually to load your scripts? `https://myexternalscript`

Comment: it's just an example

Comment: How come you want to call it? Surely it’s going to be called in the DOM anyway? What does the script even do?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a [Plugin](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/writing-a-plugin.html#Plugins-API). You will have to expand your question to show intended use.